# CentOS7 Broken after Boost Upgrade

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

Hi: I use a few static boost libraries to link against for a program I am writing. I use FindBoost.cmake to check boost is installed correctly. Everything was working until I tried to update from Boost 1.53.0 to 1.55.0. My initial install of Boost is the vanilla install from:

```
yum install boost boost-devel
```

I tried to upgrade to 1.55.0 by first installing from this kind person's repo:

```
[enetres]
name = ENETRES REPO for CentOS/RHEL $releasever
baseurl = http://repo.enetres.net/
enabled = 0
protect = 0
gpgcheck = 0
```

It installed but it didn't have what I needed so I backed it out. That process went:

```
yum install boost-1.55.0
yum erase boost-1.55.0
```

I noticed while installing 1.55.0 that it superseded my 1.53.0 install.

I then tried to install using bootstrap with the normal procedures from boost:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/bbv2/installation.html

I installed that in /opt/boost/ and after that did not work either I rm -rf /opt/boost.

Thinking I am back to normal, I reinstalled boost 1.53.0 from yum again but FindBoost.cmake no longer finds boost, *even though I see the file paths are correct to the include and library directories*.

Here is a sample of the libraries I use and I've confirmed the headers are in /usr/include/boost:

```
$ locate libboost_system
/usr/lib64/libboost_system-mt.a
/usr/lib64/libboost_system-mt.so
/usr/lib64/libboost_system-mt.so.1.53.0
/usr/lib64/libboost_system.a
/usr/lib64/libboost_system.so
/usr/lib64/libboost_system.so.1.53.0
```

When I run cmake with -DBoost_DEBUG=ON all of the path to the lib and include directories look correct.

Interesting debug output:

```
$ ./build.sh -DBOOST_LIBRARYDIR=/usr/lib64 -DBoost_DEBUG=ON
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:481 ] 
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:483 ] Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED = TRUE
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:485 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS = ON
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:487 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME = 
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:489 ] Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS = 
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:491 ] Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS = 
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:543 ] Declared as CMake or Environmental Variables:
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:545 ]   BOOST_ROOT = 
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:547 ]   BOOST_INCLUDEDIR = 
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:549 ]   BOOST_LIBRARYDIR = /usr/lib64
...clip...
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:620 ] Include debugging info:
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:622 ]   _boost_INCLUDE_SEARCH_DIRS = PATHS;C:/boost/include;C:/boost;/sw/local/include
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:624 ]   _boost_PATH_SUFFIXES = ..clip...boost-1_53_0;boost_1_53_0;boost/boost-1_53_0;boost/boost_1_53_0;boost-1_53;boost_1_53;boost/boost-1_53;boost/boost_1_53;...clip...
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:644 ] location of version.hpp: /usr/include/boost/version.hpp
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:668 ] version.hpp reveals boost 1.53.0
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:744 ] guessed _boost_COMPILER = -gcc53
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:754 ] _boost_MULTITHREADED = -mt
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:797 ] _boost_RELEASE_ABI_TAG = -
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:799 ] _boost_DEBUG_ABI_TAG = -d
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:847 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS = **/usr/lib64**;/usr/include/lib;/usr/include/../lib;/usr/include/stage/lib;PATHS;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;/sw/local/lib
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:957 ] Searching for SYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_system-gcc53-mt-1_53;boost_system-gcc53-mt;boost_system-mt-1_53;**boost_system-mt**;**boost_system**
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:993 ] Searching for SYSTEM_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_system-gcc53-mt-d-1_53;boost_system-gcc53-mt-d;boost_system-mt-d-1_53;boost_system-mt-d;boost_system-mt;boost_system
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:957 ] Searching for FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_filesystem-gcc53-mt-1_53;boost_filesystem-gcc53-mt;boost_filesystem-mt-1_53;**boost_filesystem-mt;boost_filesystem**
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:993 ] Searching for FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_filesystem-gcc53-mt-d-1_53;boost_filesystem-gcc53-mt-d;boost_filesystem-mt-d-1_53;boost_filesystem-mt-d;boost_filesystem-mt;boost_filesystem
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1044 ] Boost_FOUND = 1
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1138 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.53.0

  Boost include path: /usr/include

  Could not find the following static Boost libraries:

          boost_system
          boost_filesystem

  No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the
  directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of
  Boost.
```

As you can see I am setting BOOST_LIBRARYDIR=/usr/lib64.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Needless to say that you messed around a bit with the boost installations....but I have a question: Have you completely removed all the files generated by the previous cmake configuration run? If you use out-of-source builds, just remove the "build" directory and start from a clean state.

Comment: It is `Boost_COMPILER` which makes `FindBoost.cmake` to not find your libraries. From the `-DBoost_DEBUG=ON` output you may see this parameter is detected to be `-gcc53`, so it searches libraries with that suffix (see "Searching for ..." lines). While it is allowed to explicitely set this parameter (see [FindBoost.cmake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindBoost.html)), you cannot set it to an empty string. Not sure why Boost bootstrap creates libraries without compiler suffix.

Comment: @fedepad I did re-clone from scratch, but that didn't help. Your comment makes me think: are there other cmake config files that are stuck in a non-clean state? (Though I re-install cmake as well). Is there a .cmake config file?

Answer (score 1):

The solution makes sense, but I am confused:

```
yum install boost-static
```

OK, yes, I use Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=ON so that clue points to the solution, but I **swear** 'yum install boost boost-devel' used to install the static headers as well...